# Holonomy of a Foliation that is Transverse to the Fibres of a Fibre Bundle

Tags: manifolds, fiber-bundles, foliations, transversality, holonomy

Let $(\mathbb{E}, \pi, \mathbb{B}, \mathbb{F})$ be a **Fibre Bundle** and $\mathcal{F}$ be a $C^r$ (where $r \ge 1$) **Foliation** on $\mathbb{E}$ that is **Transverse** to the fibres of the fibre bundle $(\mathbb{E}, \pi, \mathbb{B}, \mathbb{F})$.

Let $\pi_1(\mathbb{B},b)$ be the **Fundamental Group** of $B$ at a base-point $b\in B$ and $Diff^r(\mathbb{F})$  be the group of $C^r$ diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{F}$.

Then, there is a **Representation** $$\varphi:\pi_1(\mathbb{B},b) \longrightarrow Diff^r(\mathbb{F})$$ called the **Holonomy** of the foliation $\mathcal{F}$, by the way $\varphi$ is just a **Group Homomorphism**.

The question is

How to construct this representation $\varphi$?

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right: the a foliation must also have rank $\operatorname{dim}(B)$ (such a foliation is called a [Ehresmann connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection)). Also, the holonomy representation is a map $\pi_1(B,b)\to\operatorname{Diff}^r(\pi^{-1}(b))$, which is not quite the same since there is no canonical diffeomorphism $F\leftrightarrow\pi^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: This is just the holonomy of a (flat) connection defined by the foliation (you have to assume, of course, that leaves have complementary dimension to that of fibers). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection#Parallel_transport_via_horizontal_lifts