# When does the Fibre Bundle have Discrete Structure Group?

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, diffeomorphism, foliations

Let $(\mathbb{E}, \pi, \mathbb{B}, \mathbb{F})$ be a **Fibre Bundle** ((where $\mathbb{E}$ is the **Total Space**, $\mathbb{B}$ the **Base**, $\mathbb{F}$ the **Fibre** and $\pi: \mathbb{E} \longrightarrow \mathbb{B}$ the **Projection** that is a surjective submersion)).

When do we say that the fibre bundle $(\mathbb{E}, \pi, \mathbb{B}, \mathbb{F})$ has *discrete structure group*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fibre bundle has a discrete structure group if it is defined by a trivialization $(U_i,f_{ij}$ such that $f_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\times F\rightarrow U_i\cap U_j\times F$ is defined by $g_{ij}(x,y)=(x,h_{ij}(y))$ where $h_{ij}$ is an automorphism of $F$. Note that in general $h_{ij}$ depends on $x$, for a discrete fibre bundle, $h_{ij}$ is defined by a constant map $U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow Diff(F)$.

Comment: I think $U_i\cap U_j \to \operatorname{Diff}(F)$ is only *locally* constant.

Comment: The automorphism $h_{ij}$ is of two variables  $x$ and $y$ or just $y$?  On the other hand, can you check out this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197393/holonomy-of-a-foliation-that-is-transverse-to-the-fibres-of-a-fibre-bundle

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese what is the difference between what mr. Tsemo said and what you said?

Comment: Locally constant means the function is constant on each connected component, but it is not necessarily a constant function. The distinction arises when $U_i\cap U_j$ is disconnected.

Comment: The fibre bundle has a discrete subgroup group if it is defined by a trivialization... ( this has not to be true for all trivializations).

Comment: @TsemoAristide: Ah, right. I was thinking of a trivialisation of the non-trivial $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundle over $S^1$ by two open sets. Thanks for the clarification. I guess it's worth mentioning that if a fibre bundle has discrete structure group, then the transition functions are locally constant for *every* trivialisation, but as you point out, you can choose a trivialisation for which they are actually constant.